# How to go about making this problem convex, or otherwise solving it?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have formulated the following problem:

\begin{align}
\max \quad & e^{- \boldsymbol \alpha^T \boldsymbol x/N} \\
\text{s.t.} \quad & \boldsymbol1^T\boldsymbol x = N \\
& \boldsymbol x \geqslant \boldsymbol 0 \\
& \boldsymbol 0 \leqslant \boldsymbol \alpha \leqslant \boldsymbol 1
\end{align}

Here, $\boldsymbol x$ and $\boldsymbol \alpha$ are vectors; $N$ is a scalar. $N$ is given, $\boldsymbol \alpha$ is a variable, and the optimisation variable is $\boldsymbol x$.

The objective function needs to be maximised for each $x_i$ in vector $\boldsymbol x$. But, the objective function is non-convex. How do I transform it into a convex form? Or else, how do I solve it otherwise?

Comment: picture do not load. please write down problem formulation if possible.

Comment: The objective doesn't make sense as it should be a scalar

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Is it necessary for an objective function to be a scalar?

Comment: maybe $\alpha $ is a vector too then we have $\max{\frac{e^{-\alpha^T x}}{N}}$ which is equivalent to $\min{\alpha^T x}$

Comment: Yes, how would you define the optimal point otherwise.  What is the optimal solution to $[x_1~x_2]$ subject to $x_1 + x_2 = 1$

Comment: i.e. why is, e.g., $[0.1 ~ 0.9]$ better or worse than $[0.4~0.6]$

Comment: Ok, then lets consider $\alpha$ is a vector (I'll have to think about what it means in the context of the problem, but should be ok for the purposes of this question).

Comment: In this case the problem is convex. You do not need to reformulate it.

Comment: @Alex I thought about it. If $\boldsymbol \alpha$ is a vector, then I would have to add another constraint that makes it non-convex. I have edited the question to include it.

Comment: If $\alpha$ is a vector, then we have a linear programming (LP). Solution of a LP can not be obtained in closed form but fortunately it can be solved in polynomial time (ellipsoid algorithm was proposed to prove this claim). But ellipsoid algorithm is not very efficient with large number of inputs. There is simplex method which solve problem much faster. The method you use is not important. It is important that LP's are convex and easy to solve but you need a solver to solve it. Also the region you described  $\boldsymbol1^T\boldsymbol x = N $ is a simplex which is convex.

Comment: But is the problem convex even with the constraint 0⩽α⩽1 now included?

Comment: Yup. for arbitrary constant $\alpha$ problem is convex in $x$.

Comment: As hinted above, exponential is monotonic and can thus be removed, and you have a linear program

Comment: But when I try to solve it using CVX, it gives error: "Disciplined convex programming error: invalid quadratic form(s): not a square".

Comment: Oh, both $\alpha$ and $x$ are variables. Then it is not convex as you have a bilinear product.

Comment: but I hope you realize that you can solve this problem manually as the solution is trivial.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg No, I tried. Can you please show me how?

Comment: $\alpha = 0$ is optimal

Comment: Dang! I need to change my problem formulation.